# Subtracting timestamp discrepancy

Tags: mysql

I have a persistent process which examines a row in a database table and spawns a child process on some interval, based on the last time the child process was spawned (basically, a pretty simple CRON replacement).

I had originally implemented it, simply subtracting the current timestamp from the value stored in the last_start column. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - last_start`. This *seemed* to work, however, closer inspection revealed that the timestamp subtraction was acting rather strangely.

It seemed that as we crossed the minute barrier (so, the current time ticked over to a new minute), the "difference" that was calculated would jump up by 40 (eg. from 59 up to 100). This *looks* like "1:00" - sort of - until we get to a state like that shown below, where what would be the "seconds" part of it goes above 60 (it's 95 in the example below).

I solved the problem by using the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` method to do the subtraction (thanks Stack Overflow!). But it's not clear to me why this fell short in the first place.

```
mysql db_name -e 'select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, last_start, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - last_start , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_start, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) from tasks where id = 3'      Thu Sep 11 09:49:17 2014

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP     last_start              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - last_start        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_start, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
2014-09-11 09:49:17     2014-09-11 09:37:22   1195                                  715
```

Can anyone explain to me what's happening when I just subtract timestamps, as I was doing?

Edit: The table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task` char(128) NOT NULL,
  `run_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `domina` char(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slave` char(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_start` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_end` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_duration` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_status` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What is the data type of `last_start`?  MySQL can be funky when working with dates and times that are not stored in native types.

Comment: Added the create table statement

Comment: Use `timestampdiff()` instead of `-`.  The `-` is treating the arguments as integers, which is causing your problem.

Comment: Indeed, you're right! 94917 - 93722 = 1195. I hadn't really considered  that it might be subtracting the string representation of the timestamp (in fact, the integer representation of the string representation of the timestamp) Thank you!

Comment: As I mentioned, though, I've already converted to using TIMESTAMPDIFF(), which works exactly as expected. I was really just curious about _how_ this had gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is this going wrong?  Well, you would expect that a database (or any other software product) that had a data type called `TIMESTAMP` and a "constant" called `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would represent the latter using the former.

But no.  That is not MySQL.  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a synonym for `now()`, whose type is context-dependent.  Happily, the documentation explains this quite clearly:

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
>   or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format, depending on whether the function is used in
>   a string or numeric context.

Of course, you have to figure out what the different contexts are.  A hint.  The use of `-` is a "numeric context".

What happens is the following.  MySQL sees `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and puts in the current time.   But how?  It sees the `-` and determines that it goes in as a number.  Then it comes across `last_start`.  Well, this now has to be converted to a number too.  And, guess what?  You get funky behavior.

Comment: `would represent the latter using the former` wonderful (and wonder full)